# Login does not survive refresh: how do I fix the “invalid_grant” error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

Logging in user: how do I fix the “invalid_grant” error?

1. I am using AWS Cognito,
2. I am using React and NodeJs
3. I am using a confidential client (i.e. I have a client secret)
4. My goal is to have the user log in and see their dashboard, which says “Welcome, useremail@example.com!” and ideally have this log in survive a refresh.

Current behavior: upon first log in, the dashboard says: “Welcome, useremail@gmail.com!” and the console shows a 400 error with invalid_grant. Upon refresh, a similar thing happens:

```
       POST http://localhost:4000/exchangeCode 400 (Bad Request)
Error: Failed to exchange code for tokens. Server returned: [object Object]
    at exchangeCodeForTokens (CognitoContext.js:27:1)
       POST http://localhost:4000/exchangeCode 400 (Bad Request)
CognitoContext.js:39 Error: Failed to exchange code for tokens. Server returned: [object Object]
    at exchangeCodeForTokens (CognitoContext.js:27:1)
```

And also the user is logged out (so it says only “Welcome, !”), which is not ideal.

Here is the result upon log in (no refresh yet for all of the below):

In the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
CognitoContext.js:21 Exchange Code Response Status: 400
CognitoContext.js:22 Exchange Code Response Headers: Headers
CognitoContext.js:23 Sending code:  [code here]
CognitoContext.js:39 Error: Failed to exchange code for tokens. Server returned: [object Object]
    at exchangeCodeForTokens (CognitoContext.js:27:1)
exchangeCodeForTokens @ CognitoContext.js:39
CognitoContext.js:21 Exchange Code Response Status: 200
CognitoContext.js:22 Exchange Code Response Headers: Headers
CognitoContext.js:23 Sending code: [code here]
CognitoContext.js:31 Exchange Code Response Data: Object
```

Clicking on the 400 response yields “Cannot GET /exchangeCode”.

Associated with the Exchange Code Response Status: 200 is the following:

```
CognitoContext.js:22 Exchange Code Response Headers: 
Headers
[[Prototype]]
: 
Headers
CognitoContext.js:23 Sending code: [code here]
CognitoContext.js:31 Exchange Code Response Data: 
Object
access_token
: 
"[very long token]"
email
: 
"useremail@gmail.com"
expires_in
: 
3600
id_token
: 
"[very long token]"
refresh_token
: 
"[very long token]"
token_type
: 
"Bearer"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Then, in network:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:4000/exchangeCode
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Remote Address:
[::1]:4000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Keep-Alive:
timeout=5
X-Powered-By:
Express
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type:
application/json
Host:
localhost:4000
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Referer:
http://localhost:3000/
```

This is associated with `error: "invalid_grant"`

It tells me the problematic line is: `const response = await fetch(endpoint, {`

The app client does have read access to all attributes possible, including email.

Here is how the website works:
The user clicks a button which takes them to the Cognito login page, which redirects them to the domain /dashboard upon login, and the url looks like http://localhost:3000/dashboard?code=[code here].

The following .js file in src handles context like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const CognitoContext = createContext();

const exchangeCodeForTokens = async (code) => {
    try {
        const endpoint = `http://localhost:4000/exchangeCode`;
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ code })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.email;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
};


export const CognitoProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const code = urlParams.get('code');
        if (code) {
            setLoading(true);
            exchangeCodeForTokens(code).then(email => {
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                setEmail(email);
                setLoading(false);
            }).catch(err => {
                setError(err.message);
                setLoading(false);
            });
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <CognitoContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, email, error, loading }}>
            {children}
        </CognitoContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useCognito = () => {
    return useContext(CognitoContext);
};
```

The server.js file works like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

// Retrieve client ID and client secret from environment variables
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET

// Encode client ID and secret to Base64 for authorization header
const base64Credentials = Buffer.from(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString('base64');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is running!');
});

// Route to verify Cognito token
app.post('/verifyToken', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token;
    try {
        const jwks = await axios.get('https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/[my correct User Pool ID]/.well-known/jwks.json');
        const pem = jwkToPem(jwks.data.keys[0]);
        jwt.verify(token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token verification failed', error: JSON.stringify(err) });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Token is valid', user: decodedToken });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error', error: JSON.stringify(error) });
    }
});

app.post('/exchangeCode', async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.body;
    if (!code) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Missing code parameter" });
    }

    try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('code', code);
        params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
        const redirectUri = `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`;
        params.append('redirect_uri', redirectUri);
        console.log('Sending request with code:', code);
        console.log('Params:', params.toString());
        console.log('Headers:', {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Credentials}`
        });
        console.log('CLIENT_ID:', CLIENT_ID);
        console.log('CLIENT_SECRET:', CLIENT_SECRET);

        const response = await axios.post('https://auth.realdomain.com/oauth2/token', params, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Credentials}`
            }
        });

        // Log the response data for debugging
        console.log('Token Exchange Response:', response.data);

        // Get access_token from the response
        const { access_token } = response.data;

        console.log('Axios POST Response Status:', response.status);
        console.log('Axios POST Response Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        console.log('Axios POST Response Data:', JSON.stringify(response.data));

        if (!access_token) {
            throw new Error("Access token missing in token exchange response");
        }

        // Now use the access_token to get user info from Cognito
        const userInfoResponse = await axios.get('https://auth.[real domain].com/oauth2/userInfo', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
            }
        });

        // Log the userInfo response data for debugging
        console.log('User Info Response:', userInfoResponse.data);

        // Extract email from userInfo response data
        const { email } = userInfoResponse.data;

        if (!email) {
            throw new Error("Email attribute missing in user info response");
        }

        // Include email in the response
        res.json({
            ...response.data,
            email
        });

    } catch (error) {
        const errorMessage = error.response ? error.response.data : error.message;
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('various error messages:', error.message);
          }
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Some logs I see are:

```
Params: code=[code here]&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard
Headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  Authorization: 'Basic [string here]=='
}
Received code: [code]
Sending request with code [code]

Token Exchange Response: {
  id_token: '...',
  access_token: …',
  refresh_token: '...',
  expires_in: 3600,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
Axios POST Response Status: 200
…
User Info Response: {
  sub: [sub attribute]',
  email_verified: 'true',
  email: useremail@gmail.com',
  username: '[sub attribute]'
}
Axios POST Error - Status: 400
Axios POST Error - Data: { error: 'invalid_grant' }
Axios POST Error - Headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  date: 'Thu, 19 Oct 2023 16:56:19 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
…
  'set-cookie': [
    'XSRF-TOKEN=[string]; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax'
  ],
  'x-amz-cognito-request-id': '[string]',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: '0',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
  via: '1.1 [string of numbers].cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
…
  'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
  'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=[string]"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
  nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': [string]-ORD',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400'
}
Error - Code: 400
Error - Message: { error: 'invalid_grant' }
Error: { error: 'invalid_grant' }
Failed /exchangeCode: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
    at settle
…
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization: 'Basic [string]==',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.5.1',
      'Content-Length': '126',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://auth.realdomain.com/oauth2/token',
    data: 'code=codehere&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: '126',
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
 …
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
…
    _header: 'POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
…
```

Comment: A bit hard to tell what's going on here without seeing your network logs. Is your verify endpoint being called more than once with the same `code` by chance? You might consider in your `CognitoProvider`'s `useEffect` replacing the current history item with a string that does not contain the `?code=1234` part (`history.replaceState("http://localhost:4000/home")`). That would help make sure you only ever send a code one time and not again if the user presses the back button, refreshes, etc.

Comment: If anyone finds this, the solution for me was to change from Express to Flask. It now doesn't have any 500 or 400 errors and also login survives refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is caused by leaving the authorization response URL in the browser. A refresh of the page then tries to re-post the authorization code grant request. This fails on refresh, since the authorization code can only be used once.

To resolve your problem, use code such as this in the frontend, after calling `exchangeCodeForTokens`. On page reload, the authorization code is then no longer in the query parameters. This is the technique I use in [my code examples](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L131):

```js
history.replaceState({}, document.title, '/');
```